# Using Convolution Theorem to find the Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, convolution

In previous questions I have used Laplace transform to find the inverse Laplace transform.

I have worked through this work booklet (http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap20/20_6.pdf ) and understand convolution theorem.However, this question threw me off perhaps the particular layout is the problem.

Part A which I understand how to was

$$
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
2 & \text{ } 0 \leq t < T  \\
1       &  t  \geq T
\end{cases}
$$

Part B however I dont understand

I know the convolution theorem is 
$$ \int^t_0 f(t-x)g(x)\ dx =$$

But how to apply that to

Use convolution theorem to find the Laplace transform of

$$ \int^t_0 du f_T(t-u)f_s (u), t>0 $$

where fs(t) is the function in (1) replaced with T replaced by S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LT of a convolution of two functions is the product of the individual LTs.  If you recall, we found that

$$\hat{f_T}(p) = \frac{2 - e^{-p T}}{p}$$

Thus, the LT of the above convolution is simply

$$\hat{h_{S*T}}(p) = \left ( \frac{2 - e^{-p S}}{p} \right )\left ( \frac{2 - e^{-p T}}{p} \right )$$

Comment: so essentially what 
 $$ \int^t_0 du f_T(t-u)f_s (u), t>0 $$ means is

to find the Laplace transform using convolution 

We find the laplace transform using the previous method and then we multiply the laplace transform by itself but replacing t by s for the first function ?

Comment: @SF: that is the long and short of it.

Comment: do I need to evaluate 

$$\hat{h_{S*T}}(p) = \left ( \frac{2 - e^{-p S}}{p} \right )\left ( \frac{2 - e^{-p T}}{p} \right )$$

between 0 and t ?

in my workbook we would replace the first t with (t-x) and the 2nd t with x . that does not apply in this case

Comment: @SF: No, this is the transform.  An interesting exercise is to actually evaluate that convolution - it is not trivial so far as I can see.  But you were asked to find the transform which, as I showed, is rather straightforward.